# How to test functionality of operating system while developing it?

Tags: operating-system, android-rom

I'm developing my own Android ROM. I find it is too inefficient to test my newly added functionality(made some change at boot up stage). I have to modify the code -> compile the Android system (at least 15min) -> flash to phone and see the result.

Are there any better ways to test my newly added functionality especially whose I mentioned above.

Comment: Using a virtual machine may save some time

Comment: Would you please explain it in detail?

Comment: Instead of flashing your phone, install the image in a virtual machine so you save some steps using software like VirtualBox

Comment: Thank you for your kindness.